# Multiple Foreach loops for one array

Tags: php, foreach

I have a foreach loops for an array called $feedsMerged.  I have this foreach loop near the top of a document and it's setting some global variables from the array.

I'd like to recall the foreach loop, or run it again on that array and this time build elements from the variables I set above.

Top of the document.

```
foreach ($feedsMerged as $posts) {
$post_id = $post['post_id'];
etc etc
}
```

Then bottom of page

```
foreach ($feedsMerged as $posts) {
echo '<div class="' . $post_id . '">stuff</div>';
}
```

Is this possible to do?  The reason for using two foreach loops on the same array is I'd like to keep this all organized and I'll have content in between each foreach that can't be in this foreach

Comment: I do not see why that should not be possible? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Have you tried it yet? Without more info or specific code I don't see a problem.

Comment: foreach doesn't unset anything. You can call it as many times as you need.

Comment: Interesting... I'm not getting an error, but if I echo post_id in the second foreach, nothing shows up.

Comment: Also, if I echo post_id in the first foreach, I see it.

Comment: Actually... in the second foreach loop, I am returning results for each $post but they are all the same, and the same value as the last array in feedsMerged... hmm

Comment: your second foreach does not have the line: $post_id = $posts['post_id']; (and it should be posts['post_id'] in the first loop. That is why post_id is not set in the second loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem at all. You can access an array as many times as you like using any supported method in a script.